# Bootstrap slider doesn't work

Tags: html, css, slider

I downloaded html and css codes from bootstrap then run it on my local server but the slider function doesn't work. The screen just dropped below when I click the arrow. I don't know why it doesn't work in spite of just copied the codes below from bootstrap.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-9">
                <h3>
                    Carousel Product Cart Slider</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <!-- Controls -->
                <div class="controls pull-right hidden-xs">
                    <a class="left fa fa-chevron-left btn btn-success" href="#carousel-example"
                        data-slide="prev"></a>
                        <a class="right fa fa-chevron-right btn btn-success" href="#carousel-example"
                            data-slide="next"></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="carousel-example" class="carousel slide hidden-xs" data-ride="carousel">
            <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="item active">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                            <div class="col-item">
                                <div class="photo">
                                    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x260" class="img-responsive" alt="a" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="info">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="price col-md-6">
                                            <h5>
                                                Sample Product</h5>
                                            <h5 class="price-text-color">
                                                $199.99</h5>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="rating hidden-sm col-md-6">
                                            <i class="price-text-color fa fa-star"></i><i class="price-text-color fa fa-star">
                                            </i><i class="price-text-color fa fa-star"></i><i class="price-text-color fa fa-star">
                                            </i><i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="separator clear-left">
                                        <p class="btn-add">
                                            <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i><a href="http://www.jquery2dotnet.com" class="hidden-sm">Add to cart</a></p>
                                        <p class="btn-details">
                                            <i class="fa fa-list"></i><a href="http://www.jquery2dotnet.com" class="hidden-sm">More details</a></p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="clearfix">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                            <div class="col-item">
                                <div class="photo">
                                    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x260" class="img-responsive" alt="a" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="info">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="price col-md-6">
                                            <h5>
                                                Product Example</h5>
                                            <h5 class="price-text-color">
                                                $249.99</h5>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="rating hidden-sm col-md-6">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="separator clear-left">
                                        <p class="btn-add">
                                            <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i><a href="http://www.jquery2dotnet.com" class="hidden-sm">Add to cart</a></p>
                                        <p class="btn-details">
                                            <i class="fa fa-list"></i><a href="http://www.jquery2dotnet.com" class="hidden-sm">More details</a></p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="clearfix">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                            <div class="col-item">
                                <div class="photo">
                                    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x260" class="img-responsive" alt="a" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="info">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="price col-md-6">
                                            <h5>
                                                Next Sample Product</h5>
                                            <h5 class="price-text-color">
                                                $149.99</h5>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="rating hidden-sm col-md-6">
                                            <i class="price-text-color fa fa-star"></i><i class="price-text-color fa fa-star">
                                            </i><i class="price-text-color fa fa-star"></i><i class="price-text-color fa fa-star">
                                            </i><i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="separator clear-left">
                                        <p class="btn-add">
                                            <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i><a href="http://www.jquery2dotnet.com" class="hidden-sm">Add to cart</a></p>
                                        <p class="btn-details">
                                            <i class="fa fa-list"></i><a href="http://www.jquery2dotnet.com" class="hidden-sm">More details</a></p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="clearfix">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                            <div class="col-item">
                                <div class="photo">
                                    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x260" class="img-responsive" alt="a" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="info">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="price col-md-6">
                                            <h5>
                                                Sample Product</h5>
                                            <h5 class="price-text-color">
                                                $199.99</h5>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="rating hidden-sm col-md-6">
                                            <i class="price-text-color fa fa-star"></i><i class="price-text-color fa fa-star">
                                            </i><i class="price-text-color fa fa-star"></i><i class="price-text-color fa fa-star">
                                            </i><i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="separator clear-left">
                                        <p class="btn-add">
                                            <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i><a href="http://www.jquery2dotnet.com" class="hidden-sm">Add to cart</a></p>
                                        <p class="btn-details">
                                            <i class="fa fa-list"></i><a href="http://www.jquery2dotnet.com" class="hidden-sm">More details</a></p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="clearfix">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                            <div class="col-item">
                                <div class="photo">
                                    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x260" class="img-responsive" alt="a" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="info">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="price col-md-6">
                                            <h5>
                                                Product with Variants</h5>
                                            <h5 class="price-text-color">
                                                $199.99</h5>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="rating hidden-sm col-md-6">
                                            <i class="price-text-color fa fa-star"></i><i class="price-text-color fa fa-star">
                                            </i><i class="price-text-color fa fa-star"></i><i class="price-text-color fa fa-star">
                                            </i><i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="separator clear-left">
                                        <p class="btn-add">
                                            <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i><a href="http://www.jquery2dotnet.com" class="hidden-sm">Add to cart</a></p>
                                        <p class="btn-details">
                                            <i class="fa fa-list"></i><a href="http://www.jquery2dotnet.com" class="hidden-sm">More details</a></p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="clearfix">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                            <div class="col-item">
                                <div class="photo">
                                    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x260" class="img-responsive" alt="a" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="info">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="price col-md-6">
                                            <h5>
                                                Grouped Product</h5>
                                            <h5 class="price-text-color">
                                                $249.99</h5>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="rating hidden-sm col-md-6">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="separator clear-left">
                                        <p class="btn-add">
                                            <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i><a href="http://www.jquery2dotnet.com" class="hidden-sm">Add to cart</a></p>
                                        <p class="btn-details">
                                            <i class="fa fa-list"></i><a href="http://www.jquery2dotnet.com" class="hidden-sm">More details</a></p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="clearfix">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                            <div class="col-item">
                                <div class="photo">
                                    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x260" class="img-responsive" alt="a" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="info">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="price col-md-6">
                                            <h5>
                                                Product with Variants</h5>
                                            <h5 class="price-text-color">
                                                $149.99</h5>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="rating hidden-sm col-md-6">
                                            <i class="price-text-color fa fa-star"></i><i class="price-text-color fa fa-star">
                                            </i><i class="price-text-color fa fa-star"></i><i class="price-text-color fa fa-star">
                                            </i><i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="separator clear-left">
                                        <p class="btn-add">
                                            <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i><a href="http://www.jquery2dotnet.com" class="hidden-sm">Add to cart</a></p>
                                        <p class="btn-details">
                                            <i class="fa fa-list"></i><a href="http://www.jquery2dotnet.com" class="hidden-sm">More details</a></p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="clearfix">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                            <div class="col-item">
                                <div class="photo">
                                    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x260" class="img-responsive" alt="a" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="info">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="price col-md-6">
                                            <h5>
                                                Product with Variants</h5>
                                            <h5 class="price-text-color">
                                                $199.99</h5>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="rating hidden-sm col-md-6">
                                            <i class="price-text-color fa fa-star"></i><i class="price-text-color fa fa-star">
                                            </i><i class="price-text-color fa fa-star"></i><i class="price-text-color fa fa-star">
                                            </i><i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="separator clear-left">
                                        <p class="btn-add">
                                            <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i><a href="http://www.jquery2dotnet.com" class="hidden-sm">Add to cart</a></p>
                                        <p class="btn-details">
                                            <i class="fa fa-list"></i><a href="http://www.jquery2dotnet.com" class="hidden-sm">More details</a></p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="clearfix">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

css codes

```
/* carousel */
.media-carousel 
{
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding: 0 40px 30px 40px;
  margin-top: 30px;
}
/* Previous button  */
.media-carousel .carousel-control.left 
{
  left: -12px;
  background-image: none;
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #222222;
  border: 4px solid #FFFFFF;
  border-radius: 23px 23px 23px 23px;
  height: 40px;
  width : 40px;
  margin-top: 30px
}
/* Next button  */
.media-carousel .carousel-control.right 
{
  right: -12px !important;
  background-image: none;
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #222222;
  border: 4px solid #FFFFFF;
  border-radius: 23px 23px 23px 23px;
  height: 40px;
  width : 40px;
  margin-top: 30px
}
/* Changes the position of the indicators */
.media-carousel .carousel-indicators 
{
  right: 50%;
  top: auto;
  bottom: 0px;
  margin-right: -19px;
}
/* Changes the colour of the indicators */
.media-carousel .carousel-indicators li 
{
  background: #c0c0c0;
}
.media-carousel .carousel-indicators .active 
{
  background: #333333;
}
.media-carousel img
{
  width: 250px;
  height: 100px
}
/* End carousel */
```

Comment: Its working fine, [**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/626m37q4/1/)

Comment: Reall? Mine dones't work though.

Comment: You mean Fiddle is not working?

Comment: slider dones't work

Comment: <a class="left fa fa-chevron-left btn btn-success" href="#carousel-example"
                        data-slide="prev"></a>
                        <a class="right fa fa-chevron-right btn btn-success" href="#carousel-example"
                            data-slide="next"></a>
                </div>

Comment: Do you see any error in console?

Answer (score 0):

Please add the following css and scripts in your solution and hope it would be work.

In head section scripts links

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

have look in snippet, It will work proper in full page

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-9">
                <h3>
                    Carousel Product Cart Slider</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <!-- Controls -->
                <div class="controls pull-right hidden-xs">
                    <a class="left fa fa-chevron-left btn btn-success" href="#carousel-example"
                        data-slide="prev"></a>
                        <a class="right fa fa-chevron-right btn btn-success" href="#carousel-example"
                            data-slide="next"></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="carousel-example" class="carousel slide hidden-xs" data-ride="carousel">
            <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="item active">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                            <div class="col-item">
                                <div class="photo">
                                    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x260" class="img-responsive" alt="a" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="info">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="price col-md-6">
                                            <h5>
                                                Sample Product</h5>
                                            <h5 class="price-text-color">
                                                $199.99</h5>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="rating hidden-sm col-md-6">
                                            <i class="price-text-color fa fa-star"></i><i class="price-text-color fa fa-star">
                                            </i><i class="price-text-color fa fa-star"></i><i class="price-text-color fa fa-star">
                                            </i><i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="separator clear-left">
                                        <p class="btn-add">
                                            <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i><a href="http://www.jquery2dotnet.com" class="hidden-sm">Add to cart</a></p>
                                        <p class="btn-details">
                                            <i class="fa fa-list"></i><a href="http://www.jquery2dotnet.com" class="hidden-sm">More details</a></p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="clearfix">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                            <div class="col-item">
                                <div class="photo">
                                    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x260" class="img-responsive" alt="a" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="info">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="price col-md-6">
                                            <h5>
                                                Product Example</h5>
                                            <h5 class="price-text-color">
                                                $249.99</h5>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="rating hidden-sm col-md-6">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="separator clear-left">
                                        <p class="btn-add">
                                            <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i><a href="http://www.jquery2dotnet.com" class="hidden-sm">Add to cart</a></p>
                                        <p class="btn-details">
                                            <i class="fa fa-list"></i><a href="http://www.jquery2dotnet.com" class="hidden-sm">More details</a></p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="clearfix">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                            <div class="col-item">
                                <div class="photo">
                                    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x260" class="img-responsive" alt="a" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="info">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="price col-md-6">
                                            <h5>
                                                Next Sample Product</h5>
                                            <h5 class="price-text-color">
                                                $149.99</h5>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="rating hidden-sm col-md-6">
                                            <i class="price-text-color fa fa-star"></i><i class="price-text-color fa fa-star">
                                            </i><i class="price-text-color fa fa-star"></i><i class="price-text-color fa fa-star">
                                            </i><i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="separator clear-left">
                                        <p class="btn-add">
                                            <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i><a href="http://www.jquery2dotnet.com" class="hidden-sm">Add to cart</a></p>
                                        <p class="btn-details">
                                            <i class="fa fa-list"></i><a href="http://www.jquery2dotnet.com" class="hidden-sm">More details</a></p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="clearfix">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                            <div class="col-item">
                                <div class="photo">
                                    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x260" class="img-responsive" alt="a" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="info">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="price col-md-6">
                                            <h5>
                                                Sample Product</h5>
                                            <h5 class="price-text-color">
                                                $199.99</h5>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="rating hidden-sm col-md-6">
                                            <i class="price-text-color fa fa-star"></i><i class="price-text-color fa fa-star">
                                            </i><i class="price-text-color fa fa-star"></i><i class="price-text-color fa fa-star">
                                            </i><i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="separator clear-left">
                                        <p class="btn-add">
                                            <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i><a href="http://www.jquery2dotnet.com" class="hidden-sm">Add to cart</a></p>
                                        <p class="btn-details">
                                            <i class="fa fa-list"></i><a href="http://www.jquery2dotnet.com" class="hidden-sm">More details</a></p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="clearfix">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                            <div class="col-item">
                                <div class="photo">
                                    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x260" class="img-responsive" alt="a" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="info">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="price col-md-6">
                                            <h5>
                                                Product with Variants</h5>
                                            <h5 class="price-text-color">
                                                $199.99</h5>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="rating hidden-sm col-md-6">
                                            <i class="price-text-color fa fa-star"></i><i class="price-text-color fa fa-star">
                                            </i><i class="price-text-color fa fa-star"></i><i class="price-text-color fa fa-star">
                                            </i><i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="separator clear-left">
                                        <p class="btn-add">
                                            <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i><a href="http://www.jquery2dotnet.com" class="hidden-sm">Add to cart</a></p>
                                        <p class="btn-details">
                                            <i class="fa fa-list"></i><a href="http://www.jquery2dotnet.com" class="hidden-sm">More details</a></p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="clearfix">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                            <div class="col-item">
                                <div class="photo">
                                    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x260" class="img-responsive" alt="a" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="info">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="price col-md-6">
                                            <h5>
                                                Grouped Product</h5>
                                            <h5 class="price-text-color">
                                                $249.99</h5>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="rating hidden-sm col-md-6">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="separator clear-left">
                                        <p class="btn-add">
                                            <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i><a href="http://www.jquery2dotnet.com" class="hidden-sm">Add to cart</a></p>
                                        <p class="btn-details">
                                            <i class="fa fa-list"></i><a href="http://www.jquery2dotnet.com" class="hidden-sm">More details</a></p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="clearfix">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                            <div class="col-item">
                                <div class="photo">
                                    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x260" class="img-responsive" alt="a" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="info">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="price col-md-6">
                                            <h5>
                                                Product with Variants</h5>
                                            <h5 class="price-text-color">
                                                $149.99</h5>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="rating hidden-sm col-md-6">
                                            <i class="price-text-color fa fa-star"></i><i class="price-text-color fa fa-star">
                                            </i><i class="price-text-color fa fa-star"></i><i class="price-text-color fa fa-star">
                                            </i><i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="separator clear-left">
                                        <p class="btn-add">
                                            <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i><a href="http://www.jquery2dotnet.com" class="hidden-sm">Add to cart</a></p>
                                        <p class="btn-details">
                                            <i class="fa fa-list"></i><a href="http://www.jquery2dotnet.com" class="hidden-sm">More details</a></p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="clearfix">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                            <div class="col-item">
                                <div class="photo">
                                    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x260" class="img-responsive" alt="a" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="info">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="price col-md-6">
                                            <h5>
                                                Product with Variants</h5>
                                            <h5 class="price-text-color">
                                                $199.99</h5>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="rating hidden-sm col-md-6">
                                            <i class="price-text-color fa fa-star"></i><i class="price-text-color fa fa-star">
                                            </i><i class="price-text-color fa fa-star"></i><i class="price-text-color fa fa-star">
                                            </i><i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="separator clear-left">
                                        <p class="btn-add">
                                            <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i><a href="http://www.jquery2dotnet.com" class="hidden-sm">Add to cart</a></p>
                                        <p class="btn-details">
                                            <i class="fa fa-list"></i><a href="http://www.jquery2dotnet.com" class="hidden-sm">More details</a></p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="clearfix">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

jsfiddle links

https://jsfiddle.net/6y3za13j/

Comment: Great! please add this in your solution and VOTE me